# Ошибка получения токена Imgur

Tags: api, rest, oauth2, token, authenticationtoken

При попытке получить токен из Postman для API imgur получаю ошибку следующего содержания:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Данные для генерации токена ввожу так как сказано в инструкции, [здесь](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#intro).
Подскажите, пожалуйста в чём ошибка и как её исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет параметра redirect uri, у тебя calback url в самом верху пустой, при openauth насколько помню на него будет редирект с токеном

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]